# FreeBSD 9.0 with GNOME 3

Tags: gnome, freebsd

Is this possible , to install GNOME 3 on FreeBSD , at the moment ? I did not find a clear answer about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it is still experimental.

Checkout the FreeBSD Gnome mailing list for up to date status